# how to create ResourceDictionary from a xaml file in same project in WPF-application main method?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uri, resourcedictionary

Among others I been trying:

```
ResourceDictionary localRes = new ResourceDictionary
{
    Source = new Uri("myexename;component/Locales/en-US.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
};
```

-> The URI prefix is not recognized.

and

```
ResourceDictionary localRes = new ResourceDictionary
{
    Source = new Uri("/Locales/en-US.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
};
```

-> The URI prefix is not recognized.

In project folder version/src/myexename there is Locales folder and the en-US.xaml-file in it. The exe is built in version/run so I also tried:

```
ResourceDictionary localRes = new ResourceDictionary
{
    Source = new Uri("../src/myexename/Locales/en-US.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
};
```

-> The URI prefix is not recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 2 Initializing resource dictionary from code**

```
var res = Application.LoadComponent(
    new Uri("/WpfApplication;component/Dictionary1.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
    as ResourceDictionary;
var testVariable = res["TestString"];
```

Where WpfApplication is the name of the assembly and Dictionary1 is the name of the res file (it's located directly in the project directory in this case).

And this is Dictionary1.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:clr="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication">
    <clr:String x:Key="TestString">Test</clr:String>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Original Answer**

Any reason that you want to do it in code and not in xaml ?

Here's an example from WinRT app but

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- Styles that define common aspects of the platform look and feel
                 Required by Visual Studio project and item templates -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Common/StandardStyles.xaml" />
            <!-- App specific styles -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/SomeStyles.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/SomeMoreStyles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" />
        <!-- Converters -->
        <converters:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter" />
        <converters:NullToVisibilityConverter x:Key="NullToVisibilityConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

**Edit -> Usage**

```
var resourceDictionary = 
    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ContainsKey(key));

if(resourceDictionary != null)
{
    var someVariable = resourceDictionary[key] as VariableType;
}
```

Comment: I need to get a string from the ResourceDictionary created from xaml and replace a placeholder in string with a value that indicates a file that caused error.

Comment: @matti In our app we were using `ResourceLoader` to get string values like so:  `ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView("Name of file").GetString("Key of resource value")` But we were using [Multilingual App Toolkit](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5e2a913c-709c-44e6-8b90-a552eede1903) which uses resw files and the localization is in xlf file. So maybe I've misinterpreted you question. Maybe It's better to delete the answer ?

Comment: @matti You could check this if you're interested [Using the Multilingual App Toolkit with WPF Applications](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/synergist/archive/2015/03/05/using-the-multilingual-app-toolkit-with-wpf-applications.aspx)

Comment: thanks for ur effort, but I want to know what I'm doing wrong to learn since I'm new to WPF.

Comment: Let me just check for a bit, and if I can't come up with an answer will delete this one. But I think this option for localization that I've mentioned is pretty good so keep that in mind if not for this project for another

Comment: @matti I've edited my answer, loaded a simple xaml resource file from code, however I think it is better to do it in xaml not in code.

Comment: thanks, but it does not work for me. I don't know is it because i need it in main-method before the application is even created.  xaml is no option because i have to edit the string (replace placeholder with a string)

Comment: @matti It seems very strange for me, what are you trying to accomplish exactly, why would you need the resources to replace a placeholder ... Can you edit your question with details because I feel that I'm answering different question :). I was focused on answering your question's Title, so if it's not your question it's good that you edit it maybe ...

Comment: I really don't know why I got the exception. Exactly the same works. Not even copy paste error, cause i just uncommented the lines that caused an exception. To make it even more strange these were the 1st lines in my main-method so memory shouldn't have been corrupted yet by something else. Weird indeed. Thanks for ur effort!

Comment: Hm, glad that it worked out, I was wondering if these resources are loading at later point in the app and not accessible in the main method but didn't have time to investigate any further.